# How can I make a regex that tests if a whitespace exists after each word?

Tags: javascript, regex, character, whitespace

After each word, a space is test. If there is a space(just 1), than it is correct.
I only have `/^[a-zA-Z]+$/` I am using this on js

Comment: http://www.regexr.com/

Comment: Could you provide what you're trying to match so I can have an idea of what you're trying to do here?

Answer (score 0):

Match 1 word, and repeat `1 space + 1 word`.

**Regex:**

```
/^\w+(?: \w+)*$/
```

<kbd>[regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eS7lT3/1)</kbd>

**Code:**

```js
var re = /^\w+(?: \w+)*$/; 
var str = 'word1 word2 word3';
 
if (re.test(str)) {
    document.write('"' + str + '" matches ' + re);
} else {
    document.write('No match.');
}
```

Comment: the space is after a given word. and the word consists of  english LETTERS(Uppercase or lowercase)

Answer (score 0):

This regex match every single word (regex-like word include also underscore `'_'`) in a string followed by 2 or more spaces `\w+(?=\s{2,})/g`:

A snippet of code in javascript to extract them:

```
var regex = /\w+(?=\s{2,})/g; 
var input = 'Word_1 Wrong_Word  test3 wrongWord_2  and so On  !';
var m;

while ((m = regex.exec(input)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    // The wrong words are in m[0], m[1] and so on...
}
```